# Ajax Forms Return Success

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm trying to learn from the http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started example. 
When I click submit, the alert of "Thank you for your comment" should pop up, however, it is not working for me. I was wondering if there was something you had to specifically add in comment.php that is being called by the form? Mine is just:

```
<?php 
echo $_POST['comment']; 
echo $_POST['name']; 
?>
```

Should there be like a return success or something? How would you implement it?
Thanks

Comment: Could you please post your HTML and all javascript which you are using for ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got it to work after I noticed that the page wasn't actually loading any scripts.

If you copied-and-pasted the example HTML, as I did, try changing the src of the javascript, so that the scripts load and don't return 404s.  I.e. instead of jquery-1.3.2.js, insert the full http://jquery.malsup.com/jquery-1.3.2.js.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery.malsup.com/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery.malsup.com/form/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

Assuming there's no error, the PHP engine automatically returns a 200 success code in the header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Comment: +1, however you'd probably be better off loading jQuery from a CDN.